# Custom token [node:customtoken] not available in rules action 'set a data value'

Tags: rules, tokens

I've created module with hook_token_info() and hook_tokens(). Now i can see my token in list of all availble tokens:

```
$ drush token | grep customtoken
 node        customtoken         Node related token
```

But this token is not available in rules action 'Set a data value'. What is the problem with custom token?

My rule looks like:

1. Events: 'After saving new content', 'After updating existing content'
2. Conditions: 'Content is of type'
3. Action: 'Set a data value'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### 1) The easy, but dirty way:

You can nest your tokens in an existing type (see http://drupal.org/node/1714418#comment-6468184). Eg, in hook_token_info() do:

```
  return array(
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => array(
      'site' => $my_tokens,
    ),  
  );
```

Your tokens will appear under "Site information"

### 2) The harder, but cleaner way:

Define your own rules data type with hook_rules_data_info()

```
function mymodule_data_info() {
  return array(
    'vub_events_data' => array(
      'label' => t('My Module Data'),
      'group' => t('My Module'),
      'token type' => 'my_module',
      'property info' => array(),
    ),
  );
}
```

and use this in your hook_token_info() implementation.

Comment: Hello, Bram, thank you for your answer. First way is not working for me. If you look on my first post you will see that token was added to standard type 'node', of course i've attempted 'site' too. Second way is not good because more complicated than custom token only :)

Thank you once more, I abandoned the token and chose a different solution.

Comment: Was not able to add a custom group of Tokens to the Rules UI with this answer. Believe there is a type-o in the function name, should be: `MYMODULE_rules_data_info()`. Are you suppose to use the data namespace in the token definition? In your example meaning: `'type' => 'vub_events_data',`